# Сделать, чтобы ссылки были как чекбоксы или radio

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте как сделать, чтобы ссылки были как чекбоксы или radio. 
Есть временные отрезки, нужно чтобы при нажатии на какой-то записывалось в пост данный отрезок.

Comment: `<button>`

Comment: А не лучше ли, используя JS, повесить событие записи?

Comment: Я кокрас не знаю как это сделтаь, пример какой-то можно ?

Answer (score 2):

http://xandeadx.ru/blog/css/452

застилизируйте под ссылки и все. Что-то наподобие

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" />
    <a href="javascript:;">Ссылка</a>
<label>
```